# Unable to understand sys.argv while solving the systemExit error

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to run a code,

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ("hello")
    manager()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: no such option: -f
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
SystemExit: 2
```

On running 
`%tb`
I am getting the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SystemExit                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-7c8a2c69be4e> in <module>()
    165 
    166 if __name__ == "__main__":
--> 167     manager()

C:\Users\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\click\core.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    720     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    721         """Alias for :meth:`main`."""
--> 722         return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
    723 
    724 

C:\Users\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\click\core.pyc in main(self, args, prog_name, complete_var, standalone_mode, **extra)
    706                     raise
    707                 e.show()
--> 708                 sys.exit(e.exit_code)
    709             except IOError as e:
    710                 if e.errno == errno.EPIPE:

SystemExit: 2
```

I followed the [instruction](http://TypeError:%20can't%20multiply%20sequence%20by%20non-int%20of%20type%20'tuple') and ran:
`sys.argv`

I got the following:

```
['C:\\Users\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\ipykernel\\__main__.py',
 '-f',
 'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-85f59a10-ccfe-4f4e-8ba7-72b1d24e60ef.json']
```

I really don't understand what parameters I need to pass and why?

```
def manager():
    pass
```

Comment: what is in your manager() ?

Comment: Can you give more details for manager()?

Comment: I edited @Prany.
I have `@manager.command()` before different methods. On running the file on shell, it shows the name of the functions after `@manager.command()`.

Comment: @krishna- Do you want to print just "hello" ?